# How can I call a REST API from jenkins pipeline script when the node my script run is?

Tags: windows, api, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

In jenkins pipeline script, I need to write script for following steps:

Call a REST API and get the key value returned by it

Use that key value to call another end point of that REST API.

The nodes I have in Jenkins are Windows machines. So I need a script which can run in Windows.

Answer (score 2):

You can install the "curl" on your windows nodes and then call the API using curl command, please refer the below:-

```
def API = "curl -X GET API"
def apiKey = bat (script: API, returnStdout: true)
```

**NOTE** - "**bat**" will execute it as batch script on windows node

The "**apiKey**" will contain the value returned by the API, which you can use for calling other API

You can also use the [httpRequest plugin](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/http_request/) in jenkins,

```
def response = httpRequest 'http://localhost:8080/jenkins/api/json?pretty=true'
println("Status: "+response.status)
println("Content: "+response.content)
```

Comment: Thank you.. i don't have access to those windows nodes. so is there any method other than using curl command?

Comment: Added in answer, please check httpRequest plugin